# SQL Server : column is Invalid

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by

I have to extract information from a table and calculate the commission of a seller.

```
SELECT 
    s.st_staffno as "Staff Number", s.st_name as "Staff Name", 
    s.st_position as "Job Title", 
    COUNT(r.ren_moveindate) as "Properties Rented", 
    s.st_salary * s.st_commperc/100 as "Commission"
FROM 
    dbo.staff s
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.rental r ON (s.st_staffno = r.ren_st_staffno)
WHERE 
    s.st_commperc != NULL
GROUP BY
    s.st_staffno, s.st_name, s.st_position;
```

But I get the following errors:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Column 'dbo.staff.st_salary' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>
> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Column 'dbo.staff.st_commperc' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: The error message is very clear. Either use an aggregation function (might be `SUM`) in `s.st_salary * s.st_commperc/100` or group by those columns too, depends on the result you want

Comment: Your Where clause should be "WHERE s.st_commperc IS NOT NULL"

Comment: @GordonBell good catch

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple errors.  I think you intend:

```
SELECT s.st_staffno as "Staff Number", s.st_name as "Staff Name",
       s.st_position as "Job Title", 
       COUNT(r.ren_moveindate) as "Properties Rented",
       SUM(s.st_salary * s.st_commperc) / 100.0 as "Commission"
FROM dbo.staff s INNER JOIN
     dbo.rental r
     ON s.st_staffno = r.ren_st_staffno
WHERE s.st_commperc IS NOT NULL
Group BY s.st_staffno, s.st_name, s.st_position;
```

Answer (score 0):

As in message error  you have not st_salary AND st_commperc  IN GROUP BY and are noy in aggregated function so  you should add in group by

```
SELECT s.st_staffno as "Staff Number", s.st_name as "Staff Name", s.st_position as "Job Title", 
COUNT(r.ren_moveindate) as "Properties Rented", s.st_salary * s.st_commperc/100 as "Commission"
FROM dbo.staff s
INNER JOIN dbo.rental r
ON (s.st_staffno = r.ren_st_staffno)
WHERE s.st_commperc != NULL
Group BY s.st_staffno, s.st_name, s.st_position,s.st_salary,  s.st_commperc;
```

or use an aggeìregate  function eg: sum

```
SELECT s.st_staffno as "Staff Number", s.st_name as "Staff Name", s.st_position as "Job Title", 
COUNT(r.ren_moveindate) as "Properties Rented", sum( s.st_salary * s.st_commperc/100 ) as "Commission"
FROM dbo.staff s
INNER JOIN dbo.rental r
ON (s.st_staffno = r.ren_st_staffno)
WHERE s.st_commperc != NULL
Group BY s.st_staffno, s.st_name, s.st_position;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must replace *WHERE s.st_commperc **!=** NULL* by *WHERE s.st_commperc **IS NOT** NULL* and include the aggregate function SUM() to get the total commission : SUM(s.st_salary * s.st_commperc)/100 as "Commission"